# How to prevent pointer-event outside of iframe with svg clip-path? (Safari browser)

Tags: html, svg, iframe, safari, clip-path

I have made a parallax effect on iframe, which is `position: fixed`. The iframe is inside a container which has clipped with SVG `<clipPath/>`.
It works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari browser. But in Safari it works partially. Visiblity works but not the events. the events are still available out side cliped box. So if I click outside iframe it fired iframe click event.

> N.B: Because of this approach I want to inject fullscreen ads/video iframes inside page/blog. Where I haven't access to change the page layouts or styling.

Here is my snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("outBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert('clicked outside iframe')
});

(function() {
  var splitBoard = document.querySelector('.splitboard');
  if (!splitBoard) return;
  setTimeout(function() {
    var iframeElm = splitBoard.querySelector('iframe');
    if (iframeElm) {
      var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('safari') > -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('chrome') == -1;
      if (isSafari) {
        function onMouseMove(event) {
          var viewportOffset = splitBoard.getBoundingClientRect();
          if (!(event.clientY > viewportOffset.top + 15 && event.clientY < viewportOffset.bottom - 15)) {
            onMouseleave();
          }
        }

        function onMouseenter(event) {
          splitBoard.classList.add('active');
          iframeElm.style.pointerEvents = null;
          splitBoard.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
        }
        splitBoard.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseenter);

        function onMouseleave(event) {
          splitBoard.classList.remove('active');
          iframeElm.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
          splitBoard.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        }
        splitBoard.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseleave);
      }
    }
  }, 2000);
})();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#outBtn {
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block;
}

.splitboard {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(((100% - 100vw) / 2) - 8px);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipSplitBox);
  clip-path: url(#clipSplitBox);
}

.splitboard-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.splitboard-content iframe {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: none;
}

.splitboard-content iframe {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.splitboard-content.active iframe,
.splitboard-content:hover iframe {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h3>Scroll the page</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dicta, sit sunt, consectetur beatae, eligendi quaerat cum ipsa laborum officia consequuntur facere ullam veritatis fugiat ipsam doloremque perspiciatis sapiente rem?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta voluptatem a, ipsa beatae perferendis accusantium labore dolorum distinctio aut dolor, suscipit vel culpa mollitia ratione atque iure hic illo esse.</p>

  <div class="splitboard">
    <div class="splitboard-content">
      <iframe style="background:black" border="0" scrolling="no" srcdoc='<a href="javascript:alert(`clicked inside iframe`)"><img src="http://themesity.com/wp-content/uploads/templates/dexter/img/background/bg1.jpg" width="100%"><h2 style="color:#fff; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; padding:10px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); margin: -20px 0 0 -105px">Click on the image</h2></a>'></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <svg class="clip-svg" height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipSplitBox" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon points="0 0.99, 0 0.01, 1 0.01, 1 0.99"></polygon>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>

  <button id="outBtn">CLICK HERE</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita suscipit rem modi eveniet ullam quis neque culpa vel, id a asperiores velit quam? Aut deleniti enim ab corporis nam modi!</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum ipsam excepturi, porro blanditiis libero, expedita iste voluptatibus commodi consequatur deserunt enim quas autem nesciunt recusandae sapiente totam neque mollitia quia.</p>

</div>
```

Click here to see the full Page result [in CodePan](https://codepen.io/miraz235/full/ZaQMgL)

**edit JS solution**
I have come to with Javascript solution. Hope anybody can give me any other non JS solutions.
Here is my code.

**CSS**

```
.splitboard-content iframe {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.splitboard-content.active iframe,
.splitboard-content:hover iframe {
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
    var splitBoard = document.querySelector('.splitboard');
    if(!splitBoard) return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        var iframeElm = splitBoard.querySelector('iframe');
        if (iframeElm) {
            var isSafari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('safari') > -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('chrome') == -1;
            if (isSafari) {
                function onMouseMove(event) {
                    var viewportOffset = splitBoard.getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (!(event.clientY > viewportOffset.top + 15 && event.clientY < viewportOffset.bottom - 15)) {
                        onMouseleave();
                    }
                }

                function onMouseenter(event) {
                    splitBoard.classList.add('active');
                    iframeElm.style.pointerEvents = null;
                    splitBoard.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
                }
                splitBoard.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseenter);

                function onMouseleave(event) {
                    splitBoard.classList.remove('active');
                    iframeElm.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                    splitBoard.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                }
                splitBoard.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseleave);
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
})();
```

Comment: Not really sure what clipping is supposed to achieve here in the first place ... is this going to be a more sophisticated clipping shape later or what? Because for what you have shown so far I don’t see any need to involve clipping at all - having a mere full-width _rectangle_ showing up between to different sections that are sliding “above” it should not need clipping.

Comment: Accualy I want to show an iframe inside middle of content but the iframe should not scroll when we scroll content. it should fixed position. Without clipping I can't show a fixed positioned iframe, without clipping it will show over the content and I will not see the other content with scrolling

Comment: Yeah well that is a result of that you approached this whole thing the wrong way to begin with ... this should be solved making proper use of z-index, not clipping. You have all content just “floating freely” within the DOM structure right now. Use two grouping elements around those content elements, and give them a white background. Apply z-index to make the iframe get _behind_ them.

Comment: inside iframe there will show different type fullscreen ad/video contents

Comment: I know that way @CBroe but for this I need to chang my page template layout and styling. Which I don't want to, sometime I will not able to do that, thats why I do this approache. I can inject any where inside the content in a page

Comment: You should really mention stuff like that upfront, that is absolutely relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok I am editing my question with this info.